# Matching all characters in a string except one in any position

Tags: regex, perl

How to match (preferably in perl) all strings that match the query string except one character?

Query: `TLAQLLLDK`

Want to match: `xLAQLLLDK`, `TxAQLLLDK`, `TLxQLLLDK`, etc.

Where 'x' is any capital letter '[A-Z]'.

Comment: This can be done in Python `regex` package (must be installed from pypy).

Answer (score 0):

Use alternation operator.

```
^(?:[A-Z]LAQLLLDK|T[A-Z]AQLLLDK|TL[A-Z]QLLLDK|.....)$
```

Likewise fill all..

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by writing a terrible regular expression, which will be horribly slow to build and even slower to execute, or you can just don't use regexes for things like these and write a function that just compares both strings character after character, allows for one "mistake" and returns True only if there was exactly one mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> How to match (preferably in perl) all strings that match the query string except one character?

Expanding the answer of @Avinash, by generating the required regular expression dynamically at run time:

```perl
my $query = 'TLAQLLLDK';
my $re_proto = '(' . join( '|',  map { (my$x=$query)=~s/^(.{$_})./$1\[A-Za-z]/; $x; } (0 .. length($query)-1) ) . ')';
my $re = qr/^$re_proto$/;
my @input = qw(xLAQLLLDK TxAQLLLDK TLxQLLLDK);
my @matches = grep { /$re/ } @input;
print "@matches\n";
```

(I had to include the `[a-z]` too, since your example input uses the `x` as the marker.)

If you need to do that very often, I would advise to cache the generated regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

  use strict;

  my @str = ("ULAQLLLDK","TAAQLLLDK","TLCQLLLDK","TLAQLLLDK");
  while(<@str>){

  if (/[A-S,U-Z]LAQLLLDK|T[A-K,M-Z]AQLLLDK|TL[B-Z]QLLLDK/ ){
  print "$_\n";
  }

 }
```

output:

```
ULAQLLLDK
TAAQLLLDK
TLCQLLLDK
```

Comment: This script prints only if any two of first three characters match to your query string "TLAQLLLDK"

Answer (score 0):

There are only 9 x 25 = 225 such strings, so you may as well generate them all and put them in a hash for comparison

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %matches;

my $s = 'TLAQLLLDK';

for my $i (0 .. length($s) - 1) {
  my $c = substr $s, $i, 1;
  for my $cc ('A' .. 'Z') {
    substr(my $ss = $s, $i, 1) = $cc;
    ++$matches{$ss} unless $cc eq $c;
  }
}


printf "%d matches found\n", scalar keys %matches;

for ( qw/ TLAQLLLDK TLAQLXLDK / ) {
  printf "\$matches{%s} = %s\n", $_, $matches{$_} // 'undef';
}
```

**output**

```
225 matches found
$matches{TLAQLLLDK} = undef
$matches{TLAQLXLDK} = 1
```